# Save document with dbref in mongodb spring-data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Using Spring-data-MongoDb.
In the scenario where we have the following documents

```
@Document
public class Company {
.
.
@DBRef
List<Person> personnel;
}
```

And the Person class.

```
@Document
public class Person {
@Id
public String id;

public String name;
.
.
}
```

Now if I have saved some persons in the mongodb with ids say 100 and 200, what is the best way save a company with those persons?

Comment: Looks like you need RDB in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first create a repository using for instance a MongoRepository interface. Which you autowire to some component/your application.

Then you can create and save objects to the db as you see fit. You just create the pojo with the nested person pojos and call save.

Note that the persons need to have an ID set and should exist in the database. Keep in mind there is no cascading when you use @Dbref in mongodb!

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company,String>
{

}

...

@Autowired
CompanyRepository repository

public void createCompany(String name, List<Person> persons)
{
    Company company = new Company();
    company.setName(name);
    company.setPersonnel(persons);
    repository.save(company);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to skip having the Person altogether in the createCompany? Only using the person id I mean. DBRef means from what I understand a link to another document in MongoDB, so since the Person already exist in the db it should be sufficient to just give it the id and it should link to it or am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct, and that would work in this example too. Afaik only the @Id field has to be set in person to make this work. So if you just create an "empty" person and set the id to 100/200 it should work

Comment: Lets wait a little to see if someone has a better solution, otherwise I will accept your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: A better way would be to fully manage it in Java. Since you saved the persons to db already you have them in memory, If not you can reload (from db) Somehow you are going to add these persons to the company (probably with some frontend) and you are displaying these users. So you should just add the actual user objects to the company and save it... But when you ask if it is possible to do with just the idea. the answer is yes..

Answer (score -1):

Use Lazy

```
@Document
public class Company {
.
.
@DBRef(lazy=true)
List<Person> personnel;
}
And the Person class.

@Document
public class Person {
@Id
public String id;

public String name;
.
.
}
```